# How to spawn objects and control the content in each spawn

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, text, spawning

I'm using unreal engine and would like to spawn multiple actors and control the text in each spawned actor.

How can this be achieved in unreal engine?

Comment: When you say "control the text", what do you mean?

Comment: Please be careful of the tags you select. For example, don't select [tag:game-maker] unless you're asking about achieving something in the Game Maker engine, which is not Unreal. If your question is about spawning, ask about [tag:spawning]. You can hover over a tag to get a brief description to double-check that it's right for your use.

Comment: Would be more precise in adding text tags from hereon

Comment: @Stephen I would like to change the text .That is , add text from a data table on each of the spawned actors.

Comment: Whether in C++ or blueprints, in your actor expose a set text function/method that will set the text as parameter.

Comment: @ColdSteel im using blueprints and basically I need to be able to reference the spawned character and change the text in each new spawn from a datatable.

Comment: @ColdSteel So if the data table has values A,b,c,d I need each subsequent spawn to have the text in this order.